# Ansible - How to run YAML code in Azure Cloud Shell

Tags: azure, ansible, azure-cloud-shell

**Question**: How do I run the following `YAML` in `Azure Cloud Shell`?

In step 1 of [this Ansible tutorial](https://dev.to/cloudskills/deploy-a-windows-vm-to-azure-with-ansible-2l9m), the author is asking to run the following `YAML` - to create a resource group. I'm using PowerShell in `Azure Cloud Shell` (where Ansible is pre-installed).

```
- name: Create resource group
    azure_rm_resourcegroup:
    name: rg-cs-ansible
    location: eastus
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save it to a playbook.yaml text file and run it with `ansible-playbook playbook.yaml`, but you also need to have a proper structure to the playbook file. something like this:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - name: Create resource groupf
    azure_rm_resourcegroup:
      name: rg-cs-ansible
      location: eastus
```

Comment: I ran your script in `playbook.yaml` file and got the following error - any suggestion? `ERROR! A malformed block was encountered while loading tasks: {u'azure_rm_resourcegroup': None, u'name': u'rg-cs-ansible', u'location': u'eastus'} should be a list or None but is <class 'ansible.parsing.yaml.objects.AnsibleMapping'>

The error appears to be in '/home/myaccount/clouddrive/MyTestDir/createrg.yaml': line 1, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:


- name: Create resource group
  ^ here`

Comment: probably fixed it, haven't used ansible in 3 years or something

Comment: Your fixed suggestion worked (thank you). Author of the article did not mention how to run his/her code block. Are there other ways one can run his/her block?